# using Angular ng-repeat to display JSON rows/columns

Tags: json, angularjs

The JSON I am getting back from the API is nested FIRST by field (i.e. table columns), THEN by record(i.e. table rows). So, the JSON looks like this:

```
myJSON = {
    'data':{
        'id': [1,2,3],
        'groks':['a','b','c']
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use angular to display them correctly in my table. This is how they're supposed to look:

```
id groks
 1   a
 2   b
 3   c
```

It's not as simple as

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in myJSON.data">
    <tr>
        <td>{{x[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{x[1]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Because I'll end up with this, or somesuch:

```
id groks
 a   b  
 1   2
```

So, how do I tell the ng-repeat to FIRST iterate through the inner rows, THEN through the outer columns?

The long way is to pre-manipulate the JSON into a format that can be iterated. i.e. I need to manipulate the data until it looks like this:

```
myJSON = {
    'data':{
        ['id': 1,'groks':'a'],
        ['id': 2,'groks':'b'],
        ['id': 3,'groks':'c']
    }
}
```

And then I can do this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in myJSON.data">
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.id}}</td>
        <td>{{x.groks}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But do I have any alternate options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over one of the arrays and use `$index` to get the corresponding elements in any other arrays:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="id in myJSON.data.id">
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{myJSON.data.gorks[$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That would work. Added a plunker for above. http://plnkr.co/edit/fGJ9FVgoIAGz2LPHoFsX?p=preview