# Can I use angular-tablesort on this data?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am attempting to implement angular-tablesort: https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort
This isn't an "issue" with the module, so I thought I should check here before bugging the author.

My JSON looks like this:

```
$scope.dummyJSON = {
    'data': {
        'uid': [1, 2, 3],
        'siz': ['s','s','m'],
    }
}
```

That's 3 items, each with a uid and a size value, i.e.:

```
ID SIZE
 1  s
 2  s
 3  m
```

Notice how the data is sideways (rows nested within columns - can't be helped, not my API).

I got an answer as to how to table this, here:
[using Angular ng-repeat to display JSON rows/columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658401/using-angular-ng-repeat-to-display-json-rows-columns)
Essentially, it's this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="id in dummyJSON.data.uid">
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{dummyJSON.data.siz[$index]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So far, we're all good.

Now I want to make this sortable. According to the angular-tablesort docs, it's going to look like this:

```
<table class="table table-valign-middle m-b-0" ts-wrapper>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ts-criteria="uid" class="tablesort-sortable">ID</th>
            <th ts-criteria="siz" class="tablesort-sortable">Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="id in dummyJSON.data.uid" ts-repeat>
            <td class=""><span>{{id}}</span></td>
            <td class=""><span>{{dummyJSON.data.siz[$index]}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Unfortunately, it does not work. The headers do style correctly (they hilight and arrows flip and everything), but the rows do not sort.** I suspect it's because of my wonky data structure, but I don't know. I get no JS errors, BTW.

I could use some help with either 
- massaging angular-tablesort to deal with my data structure, or
- finding a better way of rendering the data (say, without the [$index]) so that angular-tablesort has no problem with it.

Comment: try angualrjs orderBy filter

Comment: Not sure I follow. You mean, with each click, I would reorder the actual JSON, column-by-column - as in :
'uid': [3, 2, 1],
'siz': ['m','s','s']
 - and then re-render the table?

Comment: yes but you no need to re-render angular will render automatically