# turning a JSON object inside out

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to turn this JSON output inside-out. i.e. for some reason it's provided as rows-within-columns. I need it as the more conventional columns-within-rows.

This is closely related to, but not the same as, this question:
[using Angular ng-repeat to display JSON rows/columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658401/using-angular-ng-repeat-to-display-json-rows-columns)

But a new required feature is sorting on columns (using angular-tablesort), so I can't just fake up the table from the JSON output (as per the other question); the sort module chokes.

I've got to actually modify the incoming data, so it's there for the sorting algorithm. The trick to modifying it is that not all the data is in nice arrays (notice date only appesars once in the raw, but each time in the adjusted).

This is what I'm starting with:

```
$scope.rawJSON = {
    'date':'2013-04-16',
    'uid':[1,2,3],
    'foo':['a','b','c'],
};
```

and this is how I want it to end up:

```
$scope.adjustedJSON = [
    {date:'2013-04-16', 'uid':1,'foo':'a'},
    {date:'2013-04-16', 'uid':2,'foo':'b'},
    {date:'2013-04-16', 'uid':3,'foo':'c'},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var len = $scope.rawJSON.uid.length;

$scope.adjustedJSON = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
{
   $scope.adjustedJSON.push({
      date: $scope.rawJSON.date, 
      uid: $scope.rawJSON.uid[i],
      foo: $scope.rawJSON.foo[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's mostly what I'm doing but I have to make it more general. Don't know the names of the keys until I get the data, and more tricky: don't know which object is an array and which one isn't, so I don't even know how many rows there are. This is what I'm using as a test each object in a loop : Array.isArray($scope.rawJSON.data[Object.keys($scope.rawJSON.data)[i]]);
Wait a minute ... you've inspired me: if I have a uid, it HAS to be an array!